# Nunit3-console: Run tests concurrently(per assembly)

Tags: nunit, nunit-3.0, nunit-console

I've started a `nUnit3` tests on a computer that has 2 core. It seems it runs only with 1 agent.

I've read the [documentation](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Parallel-Test-Execution) but they say the `--agents=X` is to reduce the number of threads.

Why by default it doesn't use 2 agents if I've 2 cores? Should I use the `--agents=X` option?

My whole command line:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit.org\nunit-console\nunit3-console.exe" Solution\MySolution.sln --config=Debug --result=%CD%\TestResult.xml;format=nunit2
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of the NUnit console are you using?

There's an issue in v3.5, where one agent is launched per command line argument, rather than per assembly. (This is unintended.) As you're using a solution file, this would launch just one single agent.

Try specifying the two assemblies explictly, as a workaround:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit.org\nunit-console\nunit3-console.exe" aTests.dll bTests.dll --config=Debug --result=%CD%\TestResult.xml;format=nunit2
```

Issue: https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console/issues/116

Comment: We have the 3.6 version of nunit. The issue is that we have around 40 tests projects and we add some regularly.

Comment: The issue is still present in 3.6, nobodies submitted a PR to fix it yet. You could try rolling back to v3.41? You just need to update the console, the 3.6 framework should still work with it.

Comment: Do you have a link where I can find this version? I cannot get the 3.41 CONSOLE(https://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=download ) there is only the 3.5 or 3.6

Comment: Pre-3.5, the console and framework were bundled together in a single package. See: https://github.com/nunit/nunit/releases/tag/3.4.1